# Inheritance in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, components

I'm trying to understand inheritance in angular 4.

Below is my AppComponent file:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  myArray= ["1","2","3"]; //THIS WORKS
  //myArray:any; //Declared but not initialized

  setTitle(value:any){
    this.title=value;
    console.log(this.myArray[2]);

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    //this.myArray=["1","2","3"]; //THIS DOESNT WORK

  }
}
```

This is another component which extends AppComponent

```
import { Component, blurbs } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: `<p>
  title {{title}}
  <button (click)="setTitle('child')">change title</button>
</p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponent extends AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    super();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In the above code i'm calling the **setTitle()** method from the ChildComponent.

I have a console log for myArray[2].

The value works fine if i initialize the value while declaring it.

But if i just declare and initialize the array in the **ngOnInit** block the console.log doesnt work and tells me that myArray[2] is undefined.

I have a similar scenario in my application can anyone guide me what is the right approach and why its doesn't work when i initialize the array in ngOnInit block

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ngOnInit` method is redefined in `ChildComponent`, this line

```
   //this.myArray=["1","2","3"]; //THIS DOESNT WORK
```

is never executed.

If `ChildComponent` is supposed to inherit `ngOnInit` method from parent class, it shouldn't define its own method. If it's supposed to extend it, it should call parent's method:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    ...
  }
```